# run scipy scripts on another machine with the python source folder bundled with python27.dll which has no python installed

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, portability

I have a script that fits various distributions to the data and compute the distribution statistics using scipy. I want my script to run in another machine which does not have python installed.

I can package this script along with python27.dll and the entire python source folder with required site-packages, but not actually install python on the target machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: Target OS? If that happens to be Windows only, you could use WinPython which works without installation.

Comment: I get this error when I import scipy.stats  **`from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`**

Comment: I'd Google "from .ufuncs import * importerror dll load failed". There are a lot of hits.

Comment: None of them helped in my case. I tried installing numpy-mkl also